# TextBox focus border AND placeholder text

Tags: wpf, textbox, focus, border, placeholder

I want to create a textbox with placeholder text, that doesn't turn blue on mouse over/focus.

[image: Example]

Through experimentation and scouring the internet I've found that the following code is the simplest solutions to the individual problems.

**Placeholder Text**

```
    <Style x:Key="PlaceHolderTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text,
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                                            Mode=TwoWay,
                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                             x:Name="textSource" 
                             Background="Transparent" 
                             Panel.ZIndex="2" />
                    <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Panel.ZIndex="1">
                        <TextBox.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text, Source={x:Reference textSource}}" Value="">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBox.Style>
                    </TextBox>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Focus Border replacement**

```
    <Style x:Key="CustomBorderTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#000000"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

However, you can't just combine them. Putting both the grid and border in one ControlTemplate doesn't work, so how would you create a style that replaces the border and *also* displays placeholder text (preferably without code-behind)?

Comment: Why can't you combine them?

Comment: ( I cant figure out how to combine them. )   

Anyway, they both need stuff in the control template but adding the border and triggers into the PlaceHolderTextBox ControlTemplate results in "visualtree is set more than once". This is because there are 2 things; the grid with placeholder text etc and border. 
Putting border inside grid makes the error go away but it seems to be overridden or something because it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

combine them by adding a panel (`Grid`) which can have more than one child.

I took "CustomBorderTextBox" as base and added placehold TextBlock which becomes visible when text is empty. Placeholder text is stored TextBox.Tag

```
<Style x:Key="CustomTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Grid>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>

                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox}}" 
                                                     Value="">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>

                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#000000"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the solution I was looking for.